# Yii2: What is the different between a HTML table and a GridView?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, html-table, yii2

I know that GridView is PHP so it's executed in the server side and a HTML table is executed in the client side, like jQuery and Bootstrap.

I am learning Yii2 and I have been using the GridViews. It has features like the buttons edit, view and delete, and also can sort.

Now I am learning jQuery so I can make a HTML table with Bootstrap and the results are the same.

I am needing just a simple table, without the features that GridView has. I need a features: **A checkbox to each row, so the user can check some rows and send it to my PHP server**.

So I am confused. Which option is better?

Comment: Do you need any features, or are you just trying to display data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii2 GridView is a Yii2 PHP Widget  (alias  a   part of code ) for generate automatically 
 html table code starting from the configuration value  pass in the GridView Widget Call

It is extremely useful if you need to quickly build the most frequent feature for a representation in the form of a table
included filtering and sorting. 
It takes data from a data provider and renders each row using a set of columns presenting data in the form of a table.

You can see the result of the widget simply looking at the code generated  in html page in most browser  you can see the html source usint CTRL +U
(If you take a deep  look at the resulting html code you can recognize the how the tipical element for table are organized  by yii2. naming convention for id, for row and so on )

html table is a tag for the container  of the element that show the data in tablutar form

So GridView Widget is a piece of code that generate  a hatml lable stricly integrated  with Yii2 feature for filtering and ordering ..

For static data rapresentation the GridView widget is enough .. for interactive data once the datas are displayed  you must take a look at pjax and or at jquery for manage
client side the result of php widget generated  code  ..

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/

If the result of a widget is too complex for you interaction you can build a your html table looping over the result of a query, of a dataprovider  or a collection of models